# absolute positioned inner element not allowing scroll on relative positioned outer element

Tags: html, css

I need an inner div to scroll up when it is absolutely positioned at the bottom of a div that cannot contain it completely.

here is the code:

css:

```
#messages {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

#messages_inner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="messages">
    <div id="messages_inner">
        <div class="message">
            whatever
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            whatever
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

here is a fiddle of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/pwneth/xkSN2/

Comment: Firstly, you have a #messages selector but there is no id with that reference in the HTML.

Comment: i guess the solution might involve javascript and forcing scroll to the bottom

Comment: @pwneth after looking at your comments on other answers I amended mine to what I think you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkSN2/5/)

add `height: 100%;` to the div/element you want to scroll

```
    #messages_inner {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        height:100%;
    }
```

**EDIT:** after looking at your comments on other answers, I think the reason you can't do this is because of the position absolute div. Firstly, positioned absolute divs should be inside a relative positioned ones. Changed the layout a bit, I think that was the problem

[**new working fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xkSN2/94/)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
#messages_inner {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
     height: 100%;/* add this*/
    }
```

Comment: this moves inner elements to the top of the div, so no this does not work

Comment: Alexandros responded the same way and for some reason it works

Answer (score 0):

Like this? >>> [AbsolutePositioned Div](http://jsfiddle.net/xkSN2/4/)

If not please explain

```
   #messages {
        float: left;
        width: 75%;
        height: 90%;
        position: relative;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }
    #messages_inner {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
    }
```

Comment: like that except we want to see the stuff at the bottom not the top

Comment: i guess my solution will involve javascript and forcing a scroll, because i need the user to scroll up and not down when the div is too big -- think a chat program.

Comment: any update? it seems that no matter what i try, if the inner element is positioned at the bottom, there is no way to get it to scroll... even with javascript.